# Use Hamcrest to check if some elements are in a Collection

Tags: java, hamcrest

I am trying to test code where I expect a collection to have 2 of three specific values.  Is there a concise way to test that with Hamcrest 1.3?

I want something like this:

```
Collection<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("A");
set.add("B");
set.add("C");
// Remove an indeterminate element
set.iterator().next().remove();

// What the matcher actually is is the question
assertThat(set, hasSomeOf("A", "B", "C")); 
assertThat(set, hasSize(2));
```

So long as `set` contains two of the three values, the code is working correctly, and which one is missing will actually depend on `String` hash codes in the real example.

I think this might be the best way to handle it:

```
Collection<String> expected = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
for (String value: set) {
  assertThat(value, isIn(expected));
  expected.remove(value);
}
```

That also has the drawback that I cannot use additional matchers, which I would like in my real case.  (To reuse my fictitious matcher, I would like do to something like `hasSome(startsWith("A"), startsWith("B"), startsWith("C"))`

*Clarification*

If `set` contains something not in the arguments to `hasSomeOf`, then the matcher fails.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to create something like `hasSome(Matcher<Integer> countMatcher, Matcher<?>... matchers)` that would then be invoked like `hasSome(equals(2), hasItem("A"), hasItem("B"), hasItem("C"))` ?
I left the first argument as matcher too, as it allows you to have less/greater than specifics too.

Comment: What if `set = { "C", "H" }`? Check for `hasSomeOf("A", "B", "C")` would be true, and check for `hasSize(2)` would be true, but it doesn't guarantee that collection "have 2 of three specific values".

Comment: My implied semantics (which could be clearer) is that `["C", "H"]` would fail `hasSome("A", "B", "C")`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the matcher you're looking for is `everyItem()` in combination with `oneOf()` or `anyOf()`. The scenario `["C", "H"]` should fail for `hasSome("A", "B", "C")`, could be written as follows:

```java
assertThat(set, everyItem(is(oneOf("A", "B", "C"))));
```

And would result in the following failure when the item `H` were added:

```
Expected: every item is is one of {"A", "B", "C"}
     but: an item was "H"
```

For your other scenario in which you'd like to include multiple matchers, you can simply replace the expectation.

```java
assertThat(set, everyItem(is(anyOf(startsWith("A"), startsWith("B"), startsWith("C")))));
```

This would then result into:

```
Expected: every item is is (a string starting with "A" or a string starting with "B" or a string starting with "C")
     but: an item was "H"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it should be marked and the correct one.
One minor thing: i had to use `isOneOf` instead `is(oneOf(..` as i only found `isOneOf` available in `org.hamcrest.Matchers` for `hamcrest-library-1.3.0`